# Next-auth + redux

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-redux, next-auth

I've being coding since six months ago and I please need an hand on this, I'm coding this next js 13 react app with typescript and I since I rapped the Providers session={session} the redux store failed to create a store for my slice and only create a store I believe for the authentication and login here is what I see in my redux store:

```
\*
y state: {} 6 keys
canonicalUrl: " "
• pushRef: {} 2 keys
• focusAndScrollRef: {} 1 key
• cache: 1) 3 keys
• prefetchCache: (} 3 keys
• tree: {} 5 keys
```

This is my `layout.tsx`

```
"use client";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "styles/globals.scss";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import Providers from "./Providers";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { store } from "redux/store";
import { MyProviders } from "redux/provider";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { Session } from "next-auth";


const persistor = persistStore(store);

interface IProps {
children: ReactNode;
session: Session;
}
export default function RootLayout({ children, session }: IProps) {
return (
\<html lang="en"\>
\<body\>
\<MyProviders\>
\<Providers session={session}\>
\<PersistGate persistor={persistor}\>{children} \</PersistGate\>
\</Providers\>
\</MyProviders\>
\</body\>
\</html\>
);
}
```

I believe everything changed since I passed the session provide

```
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
children: ReactNode;
session: any;
}
function Providers({ children, session }: Props) {
return \<SessionProvider session={session}\>{children}\</SessionProvider\>;
}

export default Providers;
```

And this one is my store I had create at the beginning a counter slice to check if redux was working correctly and it was

```
"use client";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "./Features/counter/counterSlice";
import { encryptTransform } from "redux-persist-transform-encrypt";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig = {
key: "root",
storage,
blackList: \[\],
transforms: \[
encryptTransform({
secretKey: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY || "nonandrà",
}),
\],
};


const rootReducers = combineReducers({
counter: counterReducer,
});
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducers);

export const store = configureStore({
reducer: persistedReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =\>
getDefaultMiddleware({
serializableCheck: false,
}),
});


export type RootState = ReturnType\<typeof store.getState\>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Comment: hi and welcome, avoid using # symbols for normal text. # in markdown is a headline, so your entire text will appear very aggressive.